# How to calculate time period between two dates - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I want to calculate exact month and days between two dates.

If my start-date is "Jan 12, 2014" and my end-date is "Mar 27, 2017".

I should get as "38 months and 15 days".

But I am able to find only no. of days between start-date and end-date. I need some help to find months and days between start-date and end-date.

Then I need to divide the 15 days by no. of days of the end-date month.

Can anyone help me? I am new to date function.

```
var date = new Date();
            console.log("date: "+date);
            var currentDate = $filter('date')(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            $scope.userdob = "2017-01-29";
            var dobdate = $filter('date')($scope.userdob, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            console.log("dob: "+dobdate);

            /* differentiate Date */            
            var date1 = $filter('date')($scope.userdob, "yyyy-MM-dd");
            var date2 = $filter('date')(date, "yyyy-MM-dd");

            date1 = date1.split('-');
            date2 = date2.split('-');

// Now we convert the array to a Date object, which has several helpful methods
date1 = new Date(date1[0], date1[1], date1[2]);
date2 = new Date(date2[0], date2[1], date2[2]);

// We use the getTime() method and get the unixtime (in milliseconds, but we want seconds, therefore we divide it through 1000)
var date1_unixtime = parseInt(date1.getTime() / 1000);
var date2_unixtime = parseInt(date2.getTime() / 1000);

// This is the calculated difference in seconds
var timeDifference = date2_unixtime - date1_unixtime;

// in Hours
var timeDifferenceInHours = timeDifference / 60 / 60;

// and finaly, in days :)
$scope.timeDifferenceInDays = timeDifferenceInHours  / 24;
            console.log("timeDifferenceInDays: "+$scope.timeDifferenceInDays);
```

Comment: Why not use an existing library like Moment.JS?

Comment: Unlike seconds, minutes and hours; months and days don't have a fixed ratio. A month can be anything from `28` to `31` days. When you're going to measure things in _months_ maybe you don't need to include the days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function monthCalculator() {
  var d1 = new Date();
  var d2 = new Date('2013', '02', 12);
  var years = d1.getFullYear() - d2.getFullYear();
  var months = d1.getMonth() - d2.getMonth();
  var totalMonths = (years * 12) + months;
  var d1Date = d1.getDate();
  var d2Date = d2.getDate();
  var days = d1Date - d2Date;
  var d1LastDate = null;
  var d2LastDate = null;
  if(days < 0) {
      var d1LastDate = new Date(d1.getFullYear(), d1.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
      var d2LastDate = new Date(d2.getFullYear(), d2.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
      if(d1Date != d1LastDate || d2Date != d2LastDate) { 
          totalMonths -= 1;          
          days = (new Date(d2.getFullYear(), d2.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate()) + days;
      } else {
          days = 0;
      }
  }
  console.log(totalMonths);
  return totalMonths;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm interpreting it wrong but shouldn't it just be

```
var diffMonths = date2.getMonth() - date1.getMonth();
var diffDays = date2.getDate() - date1.getDate();
var diffYears = date2.getYear() - date1.getYear();
    diffMonths += 12* diffYears

if(diffDays<0){
       diffMonths -= 1;
       var daysInMonth = new Date(date2.getYear(), date2.getMonth()-1, 0).getDate();
       diffDays = daysInMonth + diffDays;
}
console.log('The difference between the two dates is ' + diffMonths + ' months and ' + diffDays + ' days');
```

Greetings Chris